Correspondence between elements of generalized symmetric group with different definitions
The generalized symmetric group is the wreath product $
G(m,1,n):=\mathbb{Z}_{m}\wr S_{n}$ of the cyclic group of order $m$ and the symmetric group of order $n$. In Wikipedia, it gives the generalized symmetric group as an example of wreath product:

The base of this wreath product is the $n$-fold direct product
$\mathbb{Z}_m^n = \mathbb{Z}_m \cdots \mathbb{Z}_m$ of copies of
$\mathbb{Z}_m$ where the action $\varphi:S_n \to
 \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_m^n)$ of the symmetric group of degree $n$ is
given by $\varphi(\sigma)(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n) :=
 (\alpha_{\sigma(1)},..., \alpha_{\sigma(n)})$.

From the answer I get another way to understand generalized symmetric group:  generalized permutation matrix. For example,
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \zeta_5 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \zeta_5^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
is a typical element of $\mathbb{Z}_5 \wr S_3$, where $\zeta_5 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}} \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a primitive $5$-th root of unity.
Now I wonder the correspondence between a generalized permutation matrix and an element defined as the action is in the wreath product.
Take the simplest case $G(2,1,2)=\mathbb{Z}_2\wr S_2$ as an example, the group of permutations $w$ either of the set ⁠$\{-2,-1,1,2\}$ such that $w(i)=-w(-i)$ for all $i$. For any such a permutation $w$, how to determine its corresponding generalized permutation matrix whose nonzero entries are $\pm 1$, and are the integer generalized permutation matrices with integer inverse?
And how about the general cases?

You can think of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_m\wr S_n$ as acting on the space $(R_m)^n$, where $R_m$ is the ring of $m$th roots of unity, by first doing a pointwise multiplication (via a primitive $m$th root of unity $\zeta$), then a coordinate permutation. For example, let $\alpha=[(0,1,2); (123)]\in\mathbb{Z}_5\wr S_3$. Here the first coordinate is a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_5^3$, and the second is an element of $S_3$. This acts (on the right) on $R_5^3$ according to what it does to the "typical" basis elements:
\begin{alignat}{3}
 & (1,0,0)\alpha &=& (1\zeta^0,0\zeta^1,0\zeta^2)\cdot(1,2,3) &=& (0,1,0)\\
 & (0,1,0)\alpha &=& (0\zeta^0,1\zeta^1,0\zeta^2)\cdot(1,2,3) &=& (0,0,\zeta)\\
 & (0,0,1)\alpha &=& (0\zeta^0,0\zeta^1,1\zeta^2)\cdot(1,2,3) &=& (\zeta^2,0,0) 
\end{alignat}
And these form the rows of an $n\times n$ matrix over $R_m$. For example, under this correspondence,
\begin{equation}
[(1,0,2); (12)]\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0&\zeta_5&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&\zeta_5^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Helpful answer! But you mean \begin{equation}
\alpha=[(0,1,2); (123)]\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0&\zeta_5&0\
1&0&0\
0&0&\zeta_5^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}right?

@一団和気: No. If you replace the nonzero entries with $1$, you get the permutation matrix for $(12)$.
